# Deleting entries in oracle sql developer - identifier too long

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Running a simple delete statement, the id column is a Data_Type VARCHAR2(32 BYTE). The id mentioned in the query is 32 correct? What am I doing wrong?

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE ID = B0FEA4FFB6344478E0540010E06874D8;
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA

Comment: You need single quotes if this is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM A WHERE ID = 'B0FEA4FFB6344478E0540010E06874D8';
```

The documentation and the simple suggestion of using single quotes helped. Thank you.